# How to calculate number of days between two dates in javascript in asp.net gridview itemtemplate textboxes

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview as the below image:

[image: gridview]

I have the textboxes in the ItemTemplate of the gridview. I want to calculate the number of days between the two dates and filled the last textbox with the value. I can do it in the OnTextChanged event but i dnt want postback. Plz let me how to use the javascript function?(passing textbox values and filled the TextBox)

```
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date of Submission for Xerox review" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#1B7AE0" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="10"> 
                <EditItemTemplate> 
              <asp:TextBox ID="IDDtXerox" Text='<%# Eval("Date_Xerox_Review") %>' BorderWidth="1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender3" runat="server"  Format="dd/MM/yyyy"

                                        TargetControlID="IDDtXerox" /> 
            </EditItemTemplate> 
            <FooterTemplate> 
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewIDDtXerox" BorderWidth="1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
               <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender4" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy"

                                        TargetControlID="txtNewIDDtXerox" /> 
              </FooterTemplate> 
            <ItemTemplate> 
              <asp:Label ID="lblIDDtXerox" Font-Size="Smaller" Text='<%# Bind("Date_Xerox_Review") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label> 
            </ItemTemplate> 

            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1B7AE0" Font-Size="10pt"></HeaderStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField> 
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date of ID Acceptance/Rejection" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#1B7AE0" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="10"> 
                <EditItemTemplate> 
              <asp:TextBox ID="IDDtAccRej" Text='<%# Eval("Date_Acceptance_Rejection") %>' BorderWidth="1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender5" Animated="true"  runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" TargetControlID="IDDtAccRej" /> 
            </EditItemTemplate> 
            <FooterTemplate> 
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewIDDtAccRej" BorderWidth="1" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtNewIDDtAccRej_TextChanged" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
               <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender6" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtNewIDDtAccRej" /> 
              </FooterTemplate> 
            <ItemTemplate> 
              <asp:Label ID="lblIDDtAccRej" Font-Size="Smaller" Text='<%# Bind("Date_Acceptance_Rejection") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label> 
            </ItemTemplate> 
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1B7AE0" Font-Size="10pt"></HeaderStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField> 

                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-BackColor="#1B7AE0" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="10" HeaderText="ID Process Cycle Time (Weekdays)">
                <EditItemTemplate>  
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtProcessTime" BackColor="#E3C5AF" Text='<%# Eval("ID_Process_Time") %>' ReadOnly="true" Width="50px" BorderWidth="1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate> 
            <FooterTemplate> 
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewProcessTime" BackColor="#E3C5AF" ReadOnly="true" Width="50px" BorderWidth="1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
              </FooterTemplate> 
            <ItemTemplate> 
              <asp:Label ID="lblNewProcessTime" Font-Size="Smaller" Text='<%# Bind("ID_Process_Time") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label> 
            </ItemTemplate> 
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1B7AE0" Font-Size="10pt"></HeaderStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Kindly help?

Comment: In which format date is present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function calculateDifference()
            {
                var startDate = document.getElementById("start_date").value;

                if(startDate == "")
                {
                    alert("Enter start date");
                    return;
                }
                var endDate = document.getElementById("end_date").value;
                if(endDate == "")
                {
                    alert("Enter end date");
                    return;
                }

                var startDateSplit = startDate.split("/");
                var endDateSplit = endDate.split("/");

                var stDate = new Date(startDateSplit[2], startDateSplit[0]-1, startDateSplit[1]);
                var enDate = new Date(endDateSplit[2], endDateSplit[0]-1, endDateSplit[1]);


                var difference = (enDate.getTime() - stDate.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24);

                document.getElementById("date_difference").value = difference;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date" onchange="calculateDifference()" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date" onchange="calculateDifference()" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="date_difference" id="date_difference" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanx for reply..How to pass the date1,date2 values from GridView Textboxes to javascript function. and hw to call the javascript function? as am not familiar with javascript

Comment: complete code is added, have a look. I'm using mm/dd/yyyy format for the date

Comment: thanks for the code. but my textboxes are in the asp.net gridview ItemTemplate. Will this code work with it also??

Comment: if you are using asp.net 4.0 you can give itemtemplate textboxes ClientIDMode = "Predictable". this way all your textboxes will have txtDate_1, txtDate_2 and so on. in RowCreated event of the gridview register a javascript function. you just need to get the selected textbox id append it with "_rowIndex".

Comment: I haven't used much of asp.net, but try assigning an id to your asp.net text field and execute the code

Comment: `<asp:TextBox ID="IDDtAccRej" Text='<%# Eval("Date_Acceptance_Rejection") %>' BorderWidth="1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>` in this tag, there is an `ID` attribute which can be used in `javascript` to retrieve the value. To call the javascript function, use the `onchange` attribute

Comment: Thanks everyone. Able to resolve the issue. its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try by this method:

> 1.make a function
>   2.pass textbox values
>   3. fill the TextBox

```
function get_date_difference(t1,t2){
          //  t1="10/10/2006" ;

          //  t2="15/10/2006";


       //Total time for one day
            var one_day=1000*60*60*24; 
    //Here we need to split the inputed dates to convert them into standard format
    for furter execution
            var x=t1.split("/");     
            var y=t2.split("/");
      //date format(Fullyear,month,date) 

            var date1=new Date(x[2],(x[1]-1),x[0]);

            var date2=new Date(y[2],(y[1]-1),y[0])
            var month1=x[1]-1;
            var month2=y[1]-1;

            //Calculate difference between the two dates, and convert to days

            Diff=Math.ceil((date2.getTime()-date1.getTime())/(one_day)); 
    //Diff gives the diffrence between the two dates.
        return Diff
}
```

Comment: Not getting how to pass the textboxes values which are in gridview itemtemplate to javascript function.

Comment: Don't you get textboxes values which are in gridview itemtemplate? Or you are unable to pass to javascript function?

Comment: See this link: [get and set values from gridview ItemTemplate](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=132648)